# How to groupBy an object key inside nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have a nested array of objects and I want to groupBy id and form a new array. Here's my array:

```
mainArray = [
  { name: 'a',age: 10, company: [ { desc: 'test1' , id: 6 }, { desc: 'testa' , id: 10 }] },
  { name: 'b',age: 20, company: [ { desc: 'test2' , id: 30 }] },
  { name: 'c',age: 40, company: [ { desc: 'test3' , id: 10 }, { desc: 'testc' , id: 30 }] }
]
```

I can flatten the entire array but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

My new array should look like something like this:

```
result = [
  comapny_6: [
    {
      name: 'a',
      age: 10,
      desc: 'test1'
    },
  ],
  comapny_10: [
    {
      name: 'a',
      age: 10,
      desc: 'testa'
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      age: 40,
      desc: 'test3'
    }
  ],

  company_30 :[
    {
      name: 'b',
      age: 20,
      desc: 'test2'
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      age: 40,
      desc: 'testc'
    }
  ]
]
```

I am open to suggestions on how the final data structure should look like. The bottom line is I want groupBy id so that I have information about each company separated out.

Comment: Your wanted array is invalid.

Comment: The wanted result should be an object.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We'd be happy to look at anything that you've attempted and give you feedback on how to improve it.

Comment: maybe you want an array of company objects: 


result : [
   { company_x : [...] }, { company_x : [...] } ...]

Comment: @JonasWilms it's just pseudo code.

Comment: @MaheerAli As i said the final data structure can be anything, an object or array.

Comment: @talemyn So far i just flattened the entire array and then forming my own object which is one way to do it.

Comment: @pogbamessi I have answered the question. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the array and construct the desired object output. Use `forEach` to loop thru `company`

```js
var mainArray = [{"name":"a","age":10,"company":[{"desc":"test1","id":6},{"desc":"testa","id":10}]},{"name":"b","age":20,"company":[{"desc":"test2","id":30}]},{"name":"c","age":40,"company":[{"desc":"test3","id":10},{"desc":"testc","id":30}]}];

var result = mainArray.reduce((c, {name,age,company}) => {
  company.forEach(({id,desc}) => (c["company_" + id] = c["company_" + id] || []).push({name,age,desc}));
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a 1D array using `flatMap()` and then use `reduce()` to group

```js
const mainArray = [
  { name: 'a',age: 10, company: [ { desc: 'test1' , id: 6 }, { desc: 'testa' , id: 10 }] },
  { name: 'b',age: 20, company: [ { desc: 'test2' , id: 30 }] },
  { name: 'c',age: 40, company: [ { desc: 'test3' , id: 10 }, { desc: 'testc' , id: 30 }] }
]

const flat = mainArray.flatMap(({company,...rest}) => company.map(a => ({...rest,...a})));

const res = flat.reduce((ac,{id,...rest}) => ((ac[`company_${id}`] || (ac[`company_${id}`] = [])).push(rest),ac),{})
console.log(res)
```

#### Explanation

`reduce()` is method with returns a single value after iterating through all the array. The accumulator i.e `ac` in above case is set to empty object `{}`(which is the second argument passed to function)

In each iteration we return the updated accumulator which becomes `ac` for next iteration. So what we return from function is following expression

```
((ac[`company_${id}`] || (ac[`company_${id}`] = [])).push(rest),ac)
```

`ac[`company_${id}`]` is using Bracket Notation which takes an expression `company_${id}`. It is same as

```
ac["company_" + id]
```

The above line checks if `ac[company_${id}]` exists in the `ac` then `push()` `rest` to the it.

If `ac[company_${id}]` is not created yet they set it to empty array `[]` then `push()` the `rest` to it.

The last part uses comma operator

```
((ac[`company_${id}`] || (ac[`company_${id}`] = [])).push(rest),ac)
```

The above whole expression will evaluate to the last value separated by comma `,` which is `ac`. So in each iteration we are pushing `rest` to the respective array and returning `ac` it the end. The code is equivalent to

```
const res = flat.reduce((ac,{id,...rest}) => {
    //check if company id doesnot exist as key in ac then set it empty array
    if(!ac[`company_${id}`]) ac[`company_${id}`] = [];
    //push rest(which will be an object with all the keys expect id)
    ac[`company_${id}`].push(rest)
    //at last return ac
    return ac;
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. What is this line doing ? I mean i know what's the purpose but it's hard to follow the syntax.
(ac[`company_${id}`] || (ac[`company_${id}`] = [])).push(rest),ac)

Comment: @pogbamessi I have added an explanation. Check it. If you don't understand anything feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I really appreciate it. The comma operator was throwing me off as I have never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and inside it with an [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) over the array of companies like this:

```js
let data = [ { name: 'a',age: 10, company: [ { desc: 'test1' , id: 6 }, { desc: 'testa' , id: 10 }] }, { name: 'b',age: 20, company: [ { desc: 'test2' , id: 30 }] }, { name: 'c',age: 40, company: [ { desc: 'test3' , id: 10 }, { desc: 'testc' , id: 30 }] } ] 

let result = data.reduce((r,{ name, age, company }) => {
  company.forEach(({ id, desc }) => 
   r[`company_${id}`] = (r[`company_${id}`] || []).concat({ name, age, desc }))
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```